# How to apply a filter on a title with several concatenated elements?

Tags: filter, titles

Here's an example:

```
{% set title = entry.artistFirstName | capitalize ~ ' ' ~ entry.title | capitalize %}
```

It outputs *Firstname title* instead of *Firstname Title* whereas filters are applied on the two concatenated elements. Why and how to add this filter on each of these elements?

Comment: Does it work as expected if you just use plain text?: {% set title = 'lowercase this' | capitalize ~ ' ' ~ 'lowercase that' | capitalize %}

Comment: No: 'Lowercase this lowercase that'.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested these three methods (the first one from AbbeyDesign's answer,) and they seem to work fine with variables, I can't see any obvious reason why they wouldn't:

```
{% set entry = { artistFirstName: 'hello', title: 'world' } %}

{% set title = (entry.artistFirstName|capitalize) ~ ' ' ~ (entry.title|capitalize) %}
{% set title = "#{entry.artistFirstName|capitalize} #{entry.title|capitalize}" %}
{% set title = [entry.artistFirstName|capitalize, entry.title|capitalize]|join(' ') %}
```

Results in "Hello World" in each case.

Comment: That's really strange, I tried each of your methods but each always results 'Hello world'. Note that I use this to set the <title> attribute, at the top of my _entry.html. I'm not trying to add this inside a {% block content %}. Perhaps that's why it's not working in my case?

Comment: If you're not sure about whether the block is an issue or not, it may be worth testing these on a page that isn't using extends/block/set or whatever.  Give them a shot on a basic page and try to complicate things afterwards.  In my tests, the syntax for these is working just fine as well so it's likely a larger context issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set title = (entry.artistFirstName|capitalize) ~ ' ' ~ (entry.title|capitalize) %}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for me.